# Background color works, but image doesn't. Can't figure out why

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, background

I'm creating a portfolio site and I'm only moderately competent with coding so I have been cobbling it together from various examples I can find. I've added this overlay div for the menu and I want it to have a background image, rather than just be black. However, for some reason even though I can change the color, I can't add a background image. It just won't appear. And further to that, I can't seem to add a background image on any div I place inside this overview div.

My site is http://www.madebyandrew.com

If you click menu you will see the black overlay div. I want to be able to go to my menustyle.css sheet and, to .overlay, add:

```
background-image:url('images/menu1/background1.jpg');
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything! I don't know where I'm going wrong, so I wondered if someone could help me.

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Thanks for the answers, I've tried doing the suggested of putting ../ as you can now see on the site on line 8 of menustyle.css. However, this is still not doing anything for me, and actually, I had tried this already. Any other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the full url of the image ?

Comment: I have added a background image to .overlay class and it's worked

Comment: Take a look at this http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/, and this http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `background-image:url(path)` on a .css, `path` is relative do that file.

So if you need to get the image from another folder, you should use:

`background-image:url('../images/menu1/background1.jpg')`

The two dots will make you one dir up (in your case, back to root of your site) and then find the image on the correct folder.

Comment: the `../` is changing one dir up back, but it's not to the root. To change the dir to the root, it's using `/`

Comment: @Kyojimaru - In the case of his site, is indeed the root... i'll update my response.

Comment: Ok thank you Denis I believe this has solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `background: url(../images/tc4.jpg);` css into your css file for the parent div on which your menu is shown. The image will get showing.

Answer (score 1):

just like what has been answered by [Denis Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29763084/2674662)

> When you do background-image:url(path) on a .css, path is relative to that file.

with your file `menustlye.css` (the file that contains the style for `class overlay`) directory in `/css/menu/`, if you're styling it using

```
url('images/menu1/background1.jpg');
```

it will look for the the `background1.jpg` in directory `/css/menu/images/menu1`. If you're using

```
url('../images/menu1/background1.jpg');
```

it will move 1 dir up to `/css` and find the `background1.jpg` in directory `/css/images/menu1`

which meant that your directory is wrong, so I would prefer to use the directory relative to the root, using `/` like this

```
url('/images/menu1/background1.jpg');
```

which will look for dir `/images/menu1/` from the root

Answer (score 0):

Just use `style="background: url('images/menu1/background1.jpg')"` in following code

```
![<div id="menuContents" style="background: url('images/menu1/background1.jpg')">

            <div id="menuClear">    
            </div>

            <ul id="menuList">

                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">NZSki</a></li><br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Theta</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Ports of Auckland</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Total Compliance</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Ted's Grooming Room</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Coffee &amp; Jam</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Treble Seven</a></li> <br>
                <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Diacle</a></li> <br>

            </ul>



        </div>][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you have to change little bit in your css, Try following code it may help you

```css
.example{
  
  background: url(../images/x.png) 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  height:xpx; // Give a height according to requirement
  width:ypx; // Give a width accroding to requirement
}
```

Hope it will work. other wise you have to put an image and overlay div in fixed position using opacity.